# Android docs and release key resulted in failure?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I can't seem to figure this out and adding --stacktrace was not much help.  My build of android works fine until I modify this code

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

to have the following code(notice I add 1 line to buildTypes and a whole section above it (it is all in the typical android section)

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile 'release.jks'
            keyAlias 'myAlias'
            keyPassword 'password'
            storePassword 'password'
        }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

I have tried signingConfigs and signingConfig both.  using --stacktrace yields the caused by as

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: build_esgol9ch92dhm9du29nglcr2r.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_esgol9ch92dhm9du29nglcr2r$_run_closure2) values: [build_esgol9ch92dhm9du29nglcr2r$_run_closure2@96ce4db]
```

If I remove all contents of release section, it is interesting that I get the correct error ONLY when using signingConfigs (so I suspect signingConfigs is correct even though posts were correcting others on use singular over plural)...

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':kds-android-studio:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
```

> SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storeFile".

As soon as I add another property it all fails with the very cryptic error.
Any ideas? or any ideas how to debug further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `storeFile "file.jks"` to `storeFile file("file.jks")`

Comment: OMG, thank you!!!!  I really hate groovy errors.   I wonder if android can do kotlin in build files since gradle can.  I am betting I would have better errors that way.